# Can you install slip nuts for the bath tub drain under the house?

Tags: plumbing, tub, rough-in

I'm not sure why it would matter, but I'm wondering if it is ok code wise to install the bath tub drain system at the Tee for the drain and overflow valve with slip nuts under the house. Just wondering if there is some code that says you can't do that. Any issue with a slip nut connection failing during the DWV pressure test?